# Serializing a System.Array to a XML String

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2005, serialization

I need to pass an array of strings to SQL Server 2005, and so I wrote a stored procedure which accpets a `XML` parameter and deals with it properly. My question is if there is any easy way to serialize a `string[]` to a *XML string* (not a file in the disk) directly in C# without having to code my own method using `XDocument, XAttribute` and the like.

*Example*: I want to be able to transform something like `new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }` into something like

```
<StringList><String>a</String><String>b</String><String>c</String></StringList>
```

Element tag names are unimportant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try **[`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)** if you really want to avoid writing your own code, but doing it with LINQ to XML would be as simple as:

```
XElement element = new XElement("StringList",
                                values.Select(x => new XElement("String", x)));
string text = element.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you use this method to give the name of the element from the array as well?? e.g. `values.Select(x => new XElement(array[0,0], array[0,1])));`

Comment: @ChrisHall: Sure, if `array` is a `string[,]`... it's just a constructor call, so it really doesn't care where the arguments come from.

Comment: Great! I'm not 100% with C# yet, just started a junior role. Can I be cheeky and ask how it is done please :)

Comment: @ChrisHall: It sounds like you should ask a new question with more context. I can't really tell what you're asking about yet.