# One-Liner for Xml String Deserialization

Tags: xml, string, .net-3.5

Following [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330148/serializing-a-system-array-to-a-xml-string) on serializing a `System.Array` to a Xml string, I would like to ask if anyone knows of a *one-line* instruction to go the other way round, that is, to convert a Xml string such as

`<Root><Element>a</Element><Element>b</Element></Root>`

to a `new string[] { "a", "b" }` object. I suspect that using `String.Split` would be enough for the case, but it doesn't seem like the most elegant solution, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
var data = XElement.Parse("<Root><Element>a</Element><Element>b</Element></Root>").Elements("Element").Select(e=>e.Value).ToArray();
```

I would advise making this more than one line for readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
string test = "<Root><Element>a</Element><Element>b</Element></Root>";
var results = XElement.Parse(test).Elements("Element").Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
```

1. Parse the string
2. Select the elements called "Element"
3. Select the value in the elements
4. Convert to array.
5. (Optionally)Format it so it's one line.